How to install stremio on Kubuntu LTS 24.04.1?
I'm trying to install stremio through the Konsole on Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and it's giving me the following errors:
achraf@LENOVO-20157:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i stremio_4.4.168-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package stremio.
(Reading database ... 235340 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack stremio_4.4.168-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking stremio (4.4.168-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stremio:
 stremio depends on libmpv1 (>= 0.30.0); however:
  Package libmpv1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package stremio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stremio
achraf@LENOVO-20157:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libmpv1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libmpv1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libmpv1' has no installation candidate
achraf@LENOVO-20157:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install mpv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 stremio : Depends: libmpv1 (>= 0.30.0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Can someone help me figure out the issue ?
My kubuntu installation a new fresh install. It came updated with all the packages somehow.
Thank you for reading!

It seems that deb package uses dependencies that are not compatible with Ubuntu 24.04. Please ask the developer to rebuild it.

Use the official flatpak version instead. It comes with all necessary dependencies.
First, install flatpak and add the flathub repository.
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

Now install Stremio.
flatpak install flathub com.stremio.Stremio

Here is Stremio working on my Kubuntu 24.04 setup

